# Having trouble with gpc rendering plugin for a grails 3 app

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to migrate an old grails app to grails 3. I am using grails 3.0.10. I was using the rendering plugin in my old app to generate PDFs and have a bunch of PDFs built this way which I would like to keep intact, so I'm trying to get this rendering plugin installed in my grails 3 app. As suggested, I have added the following line to my build.gradle under the dependencies:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

This seems to correctly pull this plugin .jar file and the run-app works. However, when I try to render a gsp as a PDF through my controller I'm getting a NullPointerException that is being thrown by some code in the rendering plugin.

Here's my code to generate a PDF from a controller method:

```
renderPdf(template: "/pdfs/test", model: [name : 'Amarish'], filename: 'Hello-There.pdf')
```

Since the above did not work, I also tried it separately a different way by including the pdfRenderingService in the controller through dependency injection and then tried the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/pdfs/test", model: [name: 'Amarish'])
response.setContentLength(bytes.length)
response.setContentType('application/pdf')
response.outputStream.write(bytes)
```

I am including the stack trace below. Can you please let me know how I could correct this issue?

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/testPDF
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1281) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:31) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:68) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:60) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:65) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:35) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:36) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingTrait$Trait$Helper.renderPdf(RenderingTrait.groovy:47) ~[rendering-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.svp.controller.TestController$_closure1.doCall(TestController.groovy:14) ~[main/:na]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need in your build.gradle dependencies is

```
runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.1.RELEASE"
```

and your code will just work just fine. Good luck!

You can also add the latest version from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test)

Comment: Worked great on grail 3.2. Thanks a lot! I wonder how it's possible that so many things produce errors in the Grails3 plugins...